# executing insert multiple data rows using php

Tags: php

How can I insert this generated data using multiple send when requested because I made a code just for generating data but I don't know how to execute it to insert to database after it generated.

```
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
$id = trim($_GET['current_balance']);
$limit = trim($_GET['limit']);
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "neuro");
if ($con) {
    $sql = "select * from storage_data where current_balance = `enter code 
here`'$id' LIMIT 
$limit";
    $stmt = $con->query($sql);
    $val = '';
    if ($stmt) {
        if ($stmt->num_rows >= 1) {
            $i = 0;
            $val .= '<form method="post">'
                    .'<table class="table table-bordered table-advance 
 table-hover">'
                    . '<thead>'
                    . '<tr>'
                    . '<th>' . 'Details' . '</th>'
                    . '<th>' . 'CC' . '</th>'
                    . '<th>' . 'Sec' . '</th>'
                    . '<th>' . 'Balance' . '</th>'
                    . '<th>' . 'Email' . '</th>'
                    . '<th>' . 'Password' . '</th>'
                    . '<th>' . 'First Name' . '</th>'
                    . '<th>' . 'Last Name' . '</th>'
                    . '<th>' . 'Address' . '</th>'
                    . '<th>' . 'City' . '</th>'
                    . '<th>' . 'State' . '</th>'
                    . '<th>' . 'Zip' . '</th>'
                    . '<th>' . 'Phone' . '</th>'
                    . '</tr>'
                    . '<thead>'
                    . '<tbody>';
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
                $i++;
                $val .= '<tr>'
                        . '<td hidden>' . $i . '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . '<button class="btn btn-link btn-md" 
  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i>
  </button>' . '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $row["credit_card"] . '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $row["security_code"] . '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $row["current_balance"] . '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $row["email"] . '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $row["password"] . '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $row["first_name"] . '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $row["last_name"] . '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $row["address"] . '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $row["city"] . '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $row["state"] . '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $row["zip_code"] . '</td>'
                        . '<td>' . $row["phone_number"] . '</td>'
                        . '</tr>';

            }
            $val .= '<tbody></table></form>';
            echo $val;
        } else {
            $val .= "<p class='error'>No Data Found</p>";
            echo $val;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you want. I see multiple problems with your script.

Comment: all i want to know is how can i save this generated data in sql when requested because the code above is for generating data when requested :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use prepared query for inserting the data in your table.

I don't know exactly in which table you want to insert data but below query will help that you need to add within your while loop to insert all data whatever comes in foreach.

```
// prepare and bind User Query
$queryUsers = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO 
UserTable(user_login,user_pass,name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$queryUsers->bind_param("sss",$email,$upass,$uname);

// execute Users Query
$queryUsers->execute();

// Close Connections
$queryUsers->close();
```

Comment: i tried it .. it works but instead it insert the name of Credit_card not the value of the card :(

Comment: Before execute, you need to add $credit_card = $row["credit_card"]; and $credit_card must be added in bind_param

Comment: see this example of it :- https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Also make sure that values are coming in your variables by debugging first with die like $credit_card = $row["credit_card"]; die;

Comment: oh i see lemme try it ... oh  and what is the meaning of "sss" on bind_param

Comment: sss characters represent the data types passed to the query, s means string

Comment: this prepared query will surely work if you execute it properly without any mistakes. And also its much secure.

Comment: also sss need to increase if you are inserting more variables in your query like if you are inserting 4 then ssss and if 5 then sssss and so on.

Comment: Hope you can able to do it now. And don't forget to accept my answer. Happy Coding :)

Comment: still not working it says Undefined Variable $credit_card and wrong parameter count for mysqlii_stmt::bind_param() huhuhu :(

Comment: yeh I told you number of parameters must be equal

Comment: sss need to increase if you are inserting more variables in your query like if you are inserting 4 then ssss and if 5 then sssss and so on.

Comment: send me bind_param query here

Comment: ohh i see that what the sss means it the count of values to be inserted it works thank you so much ^_^ :)

Comment: sir can you tell me what this is ?

Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean ? because it's not inserting again

Comment: actually your prepare() method returns false

Comment: have you done everything correctly? there seems to be some issue then in your query.

Comment: yes i make my query the way it's columns on database :(

Comment: I will sort out your issue in some time but first try at your end.

Comment: it's working on a single column but when i add another columns to the query  it's not working anymore :(

Comment: also values needs to be same like parameters VALUES (?, ?, ?)

Comment: if you are sending more then more will come

Comment: yeah i just added another so it becomes 2 now and the the values also turn to two question marks then the i added another S and i already identified that with $SC = $row['security_code']; then execute and the error show up but if i remain it in one column with one values it's working fine :(

Answer (score -2):

U can use the following code to insert data into sql.

```
$servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db="login";//databasenam
    //connection
    $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$db);


    $sql=$conn->query("INSERT INTO tablename values(''$variables','$variables','$variables','$variables')");
```

Comment: never use inline variables when inserting to database as it is prone to SQL injection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection